# Some doubts regarding the Paczynsky-Wiita potential for modeling accretion disk around Schwarzschild black holes?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics, accretion-disk

I am presently studying accretion processes around Schwarzschild black holes and for this purpose I am reading the classic paper by [Paczynsky and Wiita (1980)](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1980A%26A....88...23P). In this paper, the authors define the following pseudo-Newtonian potential to model accretion disks around Schwarzschild black holes:
$$V_{PW}=-\frac{1}{r-2}$$
Adding the centrifugal term (where $l$ is the conserved angular momentum), we obtain the following form:
$$V_{PW}=-\frac{1}{r-2}+\frac{l^2}{2r^2}$$

Since this potential reproduces the general relativistic results quite accurately, I tried to compare this with the effective potential obtained from General Relativity which has the form
$$V_{GR}=\sqrt{\left(1-\frac{2}{r}\right)\left(1+\frac{l^2}{r^2}\right)}$$

While comparing the two, I observed the following:

- The PW potential matches exactly at the marginally bound orbit ($l_{mb}=l=4$) where $V=1$.
- For $l<l_{mb}$, the PW curve is below the general relativistic curve.
- For $l>l_{mb}$, the PW curve is above the general relativistic curve.

I could not understand the reason behind this behavior of the potential.

**What is the physical interpretation of the fact that the curve matches exactly with the general relativistic result only at $l=l_{mb}$ and different when $l<l_{mb}$ or $l>l_{mb}$?**

The following are some figures that shows the comparison for different values of $l$:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 6]
[image: 7]